# How to get output of Kotlin IntelliJ scratch file?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

A script as simple as

```
println("a")
```

doesn't produce any output in the `Scratch output` window. I expect an `a` to appear in the output window.

I'm using IntelliJ 2019.1.2 CE.

Comment: This isn't really about programming. Perhaps you might get more targeted assistance from JetBrains? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT with steps you take and idea.log attached https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Information regarding the expected functionality

According to a question I had asked: [IntelliJ Ultimate Kotlin Script REPL skips first printed lines - Scratch Output cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838611/intellij-ultimate-kotlin-script-repl-skips-first-printed-lines-scratch-output)

It seems to be the case that the REPL wants to output per line, and will only overflow into the bottom area after a certain line length is reached.

In the question I state that I generally add some initial padding so that it always flows into the lower area with something similar to:
`repeat(10) { println("BLANK ") }`

END EDIT

You have to make sure that `Interactive Mode` is turned off at the top of the scratch window

[image]

This will cause prints to be put into the `Scratch Output` window.

Be warned, atleast in the version I have of IntelliJ ultimate 2019.1.3, the first 5-9 lines generally dont print so I do something like:

```
repeat(9) { println("blank") }
```

Comment: Meanwhile with version 2019.1.3 (Community Edition) Build #IC-191.7479.19 I have no trouble getting output in scratch files no matter whether interactive mode is on or off. I'll accept your answer because it shows effort, is a nice reminder to try this out and the question will not get more attention anyway :)

Comment: @KarlRichter Do you get the inline printing atleast?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with my previous comment. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you've defined everything inside of a function, the script won't execute the function automatically - you'll need to explicitly call the function.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own print, like this:

```kotlin
fun <T> myPrint(x: T) : T = x
```

then calling e.g.:

```kotlin
myPrint(5)
```

should show `5` in the result window.