# IntelliJ Ultimate Kotlin Script REPL skips first printed lines - Scratch Output cut off

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I enjoy using the REPL in intelliJ for coding problems like you would find on codesignal. I currently have the version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-191.7479.19, built on May 27, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.4
```

I have always been really confused by the fact that when running any of these scratch files, the first 5-9 lines I am trying to print output to will just, not exist.

Below is an example  program that would print out a pyramid of X's to the console

```
fun createPyramid(height: Int, drawChar: String = "X") {
//    repeat(9) {
//        println("blank")
//    }

    for (i in 1 until height) {
        val blank = " ".repeat(height - i)
        val row = blank + drawChar.repeat(i * 2 - 1)
        println(row)
    }
}

createPyramid(11)
```

If I have the repeat block commented out, my output looks like:

[image: cut off print]

If I uncomment the repeat I will then get output looking like:

[image: complete pyramid]

The really confusing part about this situation is the number of lines seem to be random, and there is inconsistencies in how it works.
If I do `repeat(9)` I normally get 1 actually printed out "blank"
If I do `repeat(8)` most of the time it will actually not put out the first expected "X" from the pyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output for scratches is printed right in the editor, next to the expression, that provide this output. Scratch Output tool window prints only the output that doesn’t fit into the editor.

Comment: wish it had a toggle option "All in output window"